# ecmascript-6 how to export * as NamedExport from file

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a react redux project. and in my project the structure is:

```
--Feature
---reducer.js
---selectors.js
---index.js
```

So `selector.js` for example:

```
export const featureSelectorA = () => ({

})

export const featureSelectorB = () => ({

})
```

and then I want to export all from index.js, like this:

```
import * as FeatureSelector from './FeatureSelector'
export { FeatureSelector }
```

**Question:**

What I'm asking, Is there es6 feature to reduce the code above to something like this?

```
export * as FeatureSelector from './FeatureSelector'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - use the syntax described in the proposal [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from):

```
export * as FeatureSelector from "./FeatureSelector";
```

Comment: The proposal you linked doesn't use braces, does it?

Comment: Whoops @Bergi - was looking at the other one, fixed now.